# The sum of first $n$ terms of the series $\frac 12 + \frac 34 + \frac 78 ... is$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The n term of the denominator will be $2^n$ which was obvious. Can’t seem to find the n th term for the numerator

One pattern I noticed was the nth term was always 1 + twice the previous term, but the expression $2(n-1)+1$ doesn’t work. What should I do?

Comment: $(1 - \frac{1}{2}) + (1 - \frac{1}{4}) + (1 - \frac{1}{8}) + \cdots$

Comment: Again I will mention that the general term should be given, not guessed. Otherwise there are only subjective answers, not objective answers. In this case though, I think they wanted you to relate the numerators and denominators. What's their difference?

Comment: One approach would be to rewrite the terms as $(1-\frac{1}{2}) + (1-\frac{1}{4}) + (1-\frac{1}{8}) + \ldots$, and thus split the (finite) series into two parts each of which you know how to handle.

Comment: Solve it as a GP? got it

Answer (score 2):

The general term is
$$\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}=1-\frac{1}{2^n}.$$
So the sum is
$$S=n-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^k}.$$
Can you now sum the geometric series?

Comment: True, but, check the power of the last fraction. Should be $k$.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari Thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The numerator is one less than the denominator.

The denominator of the $n^\text{th}$ term is $2^n$, and the numberator of the $n^\text{th}$ term is $2^n-1$

So, the given sum is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^k-1}{2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^n(1-\frac{1}{2^k})=\sum_{k=1}^n1-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^k}=n-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^k}$$